# How do I test a web service receiving multiple requests from its clients?

Tags: java, web-services, testing, axis

I have an axis web service deployed on JBOSS. My web service is synchronous.
So, how does a web service handle multiple requests? And how do I simulate/test that my code can handle multiple requests well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter) for this. Here's a [webservice test plan guide](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html).

That said, I agree with skaffman that Axis isn't the optimum choice for webservices. If you can, use [Sun Metro](https://metro.dev.java.net/) or [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) instead, both which are [JAX-WS](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) implementations.

Comment: Do you know of neutral performance comparisons (especially scalability) of the implementations?

Comment: No one comes to mind, but you may want to track http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/j-jws11/index.html (published Jan 19). It states that the next article would cover CXF.

Answer (score 0):

Axis isn't the most modern or performant of the web service stacks (and that's putting it kindly), but it should have no problem with a decent load of simultaneous requests. If there's going to be a problem, it's more likely to be with your own code.

The best way to test this is to use Axis to write a web service client, and use it to fire a large number of requests at your server. If you've already used Axis to generate java artefacts, it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Any numbers/comparisons on the performance issue you can link to?

Comment: No, but Axis is a first generation web service stack. For new developments, it has nothing to recommend it.